# Calling an Observable's onNext() method inside its deriving chain

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have some code like this:

```js
function getTokenFromStorage(cb) {
  // Get token from storage
  var token = getToken();

  // Feed it to callback function
  cb(token);
}

var subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(42);
var token = subject
    .flatMap(function() {
        return Rx.Observable.fromCallback(getTokenFromStorage)();
    })
    .flatMap(function(token) {
        // If the token has expired, we throw it to retry handler and
        // hope that it will be renewed somehow
        if (isExpired(token)) {
            throw 'Token has expired.';
        }
        return Rx.Observable.just(token);
    })
    .retryWhen(function(errors) {
        // Get a new token and store it to the storage
        renewToken();

        // Restart whole chain <= QUESTION HERE
        subject.onNext(42);

        // Delay some time for updating item in storage
        return errors.delay(1000);
    })

token
    .subscribe(function(r) {
        // Use token to do some authorized tasks
    })
```

And my question is:

Is it a bad practice to call an Observable's onNext() method inside its own deriving chain? Is it a smell of side-effect? And if so, how could I improve this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found it difficult to understand your question. Your `retryWhen` will repeat the observable chain for what I understand, this after 1.000ms. So it should not be necessary to do `subject.onNext(42)`. When you do that, assuming that your subject is on the immediate scheduler, you immediately restart the whole chain (as you accurately mentioned). What is then the point of restarting the whole chain after 1.000ms? You should start by explaining in plain english what you want to achieve, and then your expected output vs your input, and then the alternatives that you are debating with.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your example correctly, you could use [catch](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catchproto.md) to handle the error. 
I'm probably misunderstanding your intent, but why even throw an error? Can't you just call renewToken() when the token is expired and return the result of that?